# Git push not working in Ubuntu

Tags: git, rabbitvcs

I don't know what I'm doing wrong but I cannot make `git push` work in Ubuntu (12.10).
I already tried from command line, NetBeans IDE and RabbitVCS.

This is a list with the errors I get:

netbeans:

```
Cannot connect to the remote repository at https://myname@bitbucket.org/myname/prepo.git
```

rabbitvcs:

```
Failed to connect to bitbucket.org:8080;connection timed out while accessing https://myname@bitbucket.org/myname/prepo.git
```

terminal:

nothing is displayed, just a long wait.

Since my repository is on bitbucket and it's private, I made a public repository just to see if there are no credential problems but this doesn't work either.

Can you give me some tips for troubleshooting?
What files/configs should i verify or update?

thanks in advance

Comment: Don't know about BitBucket, but is there some way you can SSH or ping the repository directly? A quick way to test this would be to clone the repo into a different directory.

Answer (score 1):

Why is git trying to connect on port 8080? To me this is suggestive of somebody making a prior git configuration and forgetting about it. It should be connecting on port 443 for https.

So hunt out what's setting that. It's probably in `./.git/config`.

While you're at it, I would advocate swapping to connecting over ssh+git. That gives you the nice option of ssh key authentication.

Comment: this is the content of my config file: `[core]
 repositoryformatversion = 0
 filemode = true
 logallrefupdates = true
 bare = false
[remote "origin"]
 url = https://me@bitbucket.org/me/prepo.git
 fetch = +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
[branch "master"]
 remote = origin
 merge = refs/heads/master`

how can i select which port to use?